# logrotate pattern matching for daemon restart

Tags: linux, logrotate

In a setup very much like: http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/ExtendingPrivilegeSeparation I have logs located in `/var/weblog/<domain>/error_log`

I would like to use logrotate to rotate these logs 50M, gzip the rest, and keep 5.

Instead of repeating the same section over and over again, I'm wondering if I can use something like:

```
/var/weblog/*/error_log {
    missingok
    rotate 5
    delaycompress
    compress
    size 50M
    sharedscripts
    postrotate
        /opt/bw/sbin/bw_apachectl.sh reload $1
    endscript
}
```

to match the domain and use it in the script.

Answer (score 0):

I think the `logrotate.conf` man page answers this question quite nicely.

Comment: No, I didn't. My system doesn't have a `logrotate.conf` man page. I did however read `logrotate(8)`, and it does not answer my question.

There does not seem a possibility to do it. With `logrotate`, anyway.

I was hoping for an answer of the kind "No, you can't do that with `logrotate`, but you can use `zomgwtf`," or: "Yes, you can do that with `logrotate`, using this little patch" ;)

Comment: I think you'll find that appropriate man page is available online, too, and does answer your question.  Cheers.

Comment: This is the source for `logrotate.conf(5)`: http://svn.fedorahosted.org/svn/logrotate/trunk/logrotate.conf.5 -- it appear the answer is no. Which is why I've been looking into the source to add the feature

Answer (score -1):

If you zap sharedscripts, you will get one full path to a logfile at a time -- your shell script for restarting the service would have to extract that one path segment on its own (the $1 is not just the part that the glob ate up)